# Extract content with Xpath and data attribute

Tags: php, xpath

I need to extract the content of the following div tag which has the data-visible="1" attribute and contains the div id "line".

```
<div class="line-name" id="line-10" data-visible="1">Need to extract</div>
```

I tried it like that, but I dont get any result.

```
$xpath->query('//*[contains(@id, "line")]//div[contains(@visible, "1")]');
```

What is the right way to extract the content with these both conditions and get the result:

```
Need to extract
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since this is a single element you should not use `//` after `//*[contains(@id, "line")]`. Also it is a `data-visible` attribute there, not `visible`.
You can use XPath expression like this:

```php
'//div[contains(@id, "line") and @data-visible="1"]'
```

Or

```php
'//div[contains(@id, "line")][@data-visible="1"]'
```